# Why doesn't the shift operation revert on overflow in Solidity ^0.8.0?

Tags: revert-opcode, solidity-0.8.x, bit-manipulation

Take the following function:

```
solidity ^0.8.0;

function foo(uint256 x) external pure returns (uint256) {
    uint256 y = x << 255;
    return y;
}
```

If you set x = 2, the result is 2**256, which is above the maximum value allowed by uint256. Yet the contract call doesn't revert. Why?

As per the [documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.2/types.html?highlight=shift#shifts):

> For positive and negative `x` values, `x << y` is equivalent to `x * 2**y`

If I rewrite the function above as `y = x * 2*255`, the contract call does revert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's designed to be that way.

The shift operation is not classified as an arithmetic operation. As per the discussion I had with @chriseth in the [Solidity gitter channel](https://gitter.im/ethereum/solidity):

[image: Solidity Gitter discussion]